# Font wont be color chosen by CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have this page http://www.beatinganger.com/guildford/course-dates

On the thead of the table I have several headings that are links, that are the color of the main container css (red), however I can't seem to change it to white as the main containers css is automatically chosen, disregarding the css I have created.

This is the css I have.  thead a color is showing as #9D2B2A and not white.

```
#left_container a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #9D2B2A;
}

thead a {
color: white;
}

th a {
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're suffering from `specificity` - http://eriestuff.blogspot.com/2007/11/css-cascade-what-defenition-takes.html

The id of `#left_container` is more specific than `th` or `thead`, so it takes priority.

Use `#left_container th a` or `#left_container thead a` to see your styles take effect.

Comment: +1 So is specificity some kind of disease now? That must be why people are prescribing `!important` as a drug :P

Comment: It is indeed a terrible affliction, but `!important` is a poor solution, the kind of thing a quack would prescribe. The proper treatment is to take your CSS to a qualified programmer and have him operate on your selectors to optimise them :P

Comment: @user1195095 By the way, mind clicking the big tick just to the left of this answer? Accepting an answer will help you get more answers to your future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an id selector on the container it is more specific than thead a which is a more general selector it is using the container one. Try putting the #left_container before thead a and th a.

```
#left_container a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #9D2B2A;
}

#left_container thead a {
color: white;
}

#left_container th a {
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

id selector + type selector is more specific than two type selectors, so that rule wins in the cascade chain.

You need to make your selectors [more specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) (or use the one-shot sledgehammer of an abomination that is [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)).

Answer (score 0):

It's because that "#left_container a" have a higher priority

you can see [css-priority-order-tips-tricks](http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/)